# What is the minimum distance between two opposite point charges

Tags: electrostatics

In an overly simplistic model if I have a single negative charge, and a single positive charge they will be attracted.  I expect they will fly together.  Click.  Good luck getting them apart.  The force required to pull them apart could be impossibly huge since the distance between them is really small.  The work required to get them to any large distance must be really high.

If I wanted to write a simple point charge simulator what would be a realistic minimum distance?

Is it true that outer electrons in metals "park" in a place that is relatively far away from the protons so the force to remove them isn't too great.  How far away is it?

Just wondering...

Comment: The true behavior of conduction electrons in a metal is deeply and fundamentally quantum in nature. Do your have any desire to generate a simulation realistic and the level, and if so how is your quantum mechanics?

Comment: My QM is 30+ years old.  All but gone.  I remember being amazed at how incalculable it all was.  I figured I'd never need to know it.  But now I'd love to understand something I'm measuring.  It seems like it should be a simple statics problem but I can see from the measurements something more interesting is going on.

Answer (score 5):

There's no *minimum distance*.

Yet, as the two particles get closer to each other, they will either *scatter* off each other (in the quantum mechanical sense of interacting via [Feynman diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)) or form a bound system - if we're talking electron-positron (which is as close to *point charges* as it gets), they might become [positronium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), but that won't last long, if they are electron-proton, they might become hydrogen, etc.

Aside from this, at the level where quantum effects kick in, the "distance" of the charges is rather ill-defined. Even in bound states, the orbitals describing the position of the electrons around the nucleus do not have constant distance to it.

It is not the case that the electromagnetic force becomes "invalid" at any range. It is just that, on very short distances, our classical picture of the force simply providing a pull/push according to Coulomb's law is invalid - the classical force arises from the tree-level Feynman diagram (one photon exchanged) between charges, while the underlying interaction in the quantum field theory is much more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

What we know is that the electrostatic force does not work nearby the nucleus. The interaction between the positive and the negative charged particles stops at some distance, where Quantum Mechanics describes it. These distances for small orbits are well studied. To calculate them is much more difficult, for the hydrogen atom you have the formula, for all other atoms  QM  calculations use numerical methods.

Your thought about the "fly together" of protons and electrons does happens in neutron stars under the condition of much larger gravitation.

The radius of a hydrogen atom is approx.31±5 pm. The radius of the proton is about ten thousand times smaller (smaller 1 fm).

Comment: You say *What we know is that the electrostatic force does not work nearby the nucleus* and while I know what you mean I think this is misleading. The potential remains $\propto 1/r$ right zero distance (ignoring QFT corrections).

Comment: So I assume this is really the potential well stuff from QM.  Schrodinger, eigenvalues, ideas that get crazy hard to compute. I'm kind of wondering if someone has a hack that can be applied to simplistic model that will kind of make it work.  Like a table of minimum distances for a conductor and an insulator that give representative values.

Comment: Aside from the EM force acting *at all ranges*, it should also be noted that the QM orbits *are not classical orbits*, and that the electrons do not maintain a constant distance to the nucleus (they aren't even localized as particles unless something interacts with them).